# Gulp AWS Publish. How to remove *.html extension and then add content-type to text/html?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gulp, content-type, gulp-rename

I'm new to gulp.  I'm using a gulp task to do an AWS publish.  Before publishing, I want to rename all html files with no extension (i.e., remove extensions).

Then publish the content with two different headers in order to force content-type to 'text/html' for HTML files.

- IF the file is html (which I already removed the html extension) then use *htmlHeaders* where content-type is mentioned as 'text/html',
- ELSE use *normalHeaders* where no content-type is used.

Since I have already removed that .html file extension, I couldn't find the condition to do publish based on any condition.

The code below removes the html extension, but don't add different headers based on file type.  How do I pipe *publisher.publish(htmlHeaders)* or *publisher.publish(normalHeaders)* based on file types?

```
gulp.task('aws-staging-main', function () {
  var publisher = awspublish.create(
    {
      region: "us-east-1",
      params: {
        Bucket: "<my bucket>"
      },
      accessKeyId: "<my access key>",
      secretAccessKey: "<my secret access key>"
    }
  );

  var normalHeaders = {
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=315360000, no-transform, public",
  };
  var htmlHeaders = {
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=315360000, no-transform, public",
    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
  };
  var cfSettings = {
    distribution: '<my distribution>',
      accessKeyId: "<my key>",
      secretAccessKey: "<my secret key>",
    wait: true,
    originPath: '/dist',
  }

  return (
    gulp.src(Paths.DIST_ALL)
      .pipe(rename(function (path){
        if( path.extname === '.html')
              path.extname = "";            
        }))
      .pipe(publisher.publish(normalHeaders));
      .pipe(cloudfront(cfSettings))
      .pipe(awspublish.reporter())
  );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this working, I made two different gulp.src for sourcing HTML files separately and other files separately, then merged them using "merge2" as below.

```
var StreamAllExclHtml=gulp.src([Paths.DIST_ALL,Paths.DIST_ALL_NOT_HTML])
                      .pipe(publisher.publish(normalHeaders));

var StreamHtml=gulp.src(Paths.DIST_HTML)
               .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                   if (path.basename != "index") {
                        path.extname = "";
                    }
               }))
              .pipe(publisher.publish(htmlHeaders)); 
  return(
  merge(StreamAllExclHtml,StreamHtml)
  .pipe(publisher.sync('',whitelist.whitelist))
  .pipe(cloudfront(cfSettings))
  .pipe(awspublish.reporter())
)
```